# How to tell application whether to use web.config or appsettings.config values?

Tags: c#, json, configuration, asp.net-core

We are converting an existing web application over to .NET Core. While in the process, we would like to be able to access both the web.config and the appsettings.config. In order to do so, we are creating a `MySiteConfigurationManager` class so that we can just do a quick find a replace for all of the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Datawarehouse.ConnectionString."]` instances. Inside of the custom indexer property similarly called `AppSettings[string key]` of my `MySiteConfigurationManager`class I plan to do something similar to the following:

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        if (!key.Contains(":"))
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
        }

        return //some code here to access the appsettings.json value
    }
}
```

Now I could just `StreamRead` the file itself and get the value needed but I am not sure if there is another way to access the appsettings.json values. As an example both of the following might appear in the project trying to access a configuration value:

```
MySiteConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audit.DisableLogging"];
MySiteConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MRU:ItemLimit"]
```

My goal is for both to be able to work seamlessly if possible.

Comment: you cannot use ConfigurationManager at all in asp.net core. web.config file is not used by asp.net core apps at all but is still used only for IIS settings if hosted in IIS